# Interpolation using interp3 on Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have been trying to use the interp3 function on Matlab but I keep getting an error.

I have 4 columns of data, and have sample points which I want to interpolate to get the value of the 4th column:

I have tried the following:

```
model_data = readtable('example_csv.csv');

model_a = model_data.a;
model_b = model_data.b;
model_c = model_data.c;
model_d = model_data.d;

query_data = readtable('query_points.csv');
query_a = query_data.a;
query_b = query_data.b;
query_c = query_data.c;

interp_d = interp3(model_a, model_b, model_c, model_d, query_a, query_b, query_c);
```

but I get the error

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
Interpolation requires at least two sample points for each grid dimension.

Error in interp3 (line 132)
        F = griddedInterpolant({X, Y, Z}, V, method,extrap);
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The error messages gives you a hint: look in the worspace browser (or use `whos`) to check the number of data points in `model_a`, `model_b`, `model_c` and `model_d`. Apparently one of them is scalar (has only one point). Either your original data are incomplete, or your import method has to be refined.

Comment: You did not supply a reproducible example, how do your variables look like? use `disp` in matlab and copy paste them.